# Support of position and sizing with Pixate Freestyle for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, pixate

Is it possible to resize and/or position the default GUI controls with Pixate Freestyle for Android? Although height, top, left are mentioned in the Style reference http://pixate.github.io/pixate-freestyle-android/style-reference/ I'm not able to see any change using these attributes.

Cheers

Comment: neither am I. PXStylerContext.getTop() is never called afaics